# C# - Access values of a JsonSerializer object

Tags: c#

How can I access values of a JsonSerializer object?

My current code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader re = new StreamReader("youtube_client_secret.json");
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
    JsonSerializer se = new JsonSerializer();
    object parsedData = se.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

How could I access the value stored in client_id ? I've been trying the following, which did not work out:

```
MessageBox.Show(parsedData["client_id"]);
```

Comment: `parsedData.["client_id"].ToString()`

Comment: Error: Identifier expected

Comment: try without the extra `.` - so `parsedData["client_id"]`

Comment: that was my first try as u see in my post: MessageBox.Show(parsedData["client_id"]);

Comment: @d45ndx Marc Gravell means to do this.. `parsedData["client_id"].ToString()` .  Sorry can't edit my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic and efficient way would be to use `Deserialize<T>` to deserialize *into a well known type* that has an appropriate `client_id` property:

```
 var customer = se.Deserialize<Customer>(reader);
 var id = customer.client_id;
```

Comment: So i should create a class containing a get/set and get the values from there?

Comment: Yes.  I'd recommend using Visual Studio's "Paste Special" to automatically create a class from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`string parsedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);`

`MessageBox.Show(parsedData);`

Answer (score 0):

use "dynamic" instead of "object" data Type. Then you can access that as below

```
dynamic parsedData = se.Deserialize(reader);
var id = parsedData.client_id;
```